Conditionally replacing all values in large polars dataframe with specific string using lambda function
How would you replace all integer values in a large multi-column polars data matrix that are >9999 with a string "10K+"?
I tried df.map, df.apply, and df.applymap:
labels = df.map(lambda v: '10K+' if v > 10000 else v)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'. Did you mean: 'max'?
labels = df.apply(lambda v: '10K+' if v > 10000 else v)
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'
labels = df.applymap(lambda v: '10K+' if v > 10000 else v)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'applymap'

Can you show a minimal input/output code example? This operation would mean changing the type of the column to string (columns in Polars have a single type) - is this what you intend?

Use a when-then expression.
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'Col1': [2, 74, 37, 36, 95],
    'Col2': [36, 80, 9, 26, 16],
}) * 1_000
df.with_columns([
    pl.when(pl.col(i) > 10_000).then(pl.lit('10K+'))
    .otherwise(pl.col(i).cast(pl.String)).alias(i) 
    for i in df.columns
])
# shape: (5, 2)
# ┌──────┬──────┐
# │ Col1 ┆ Col2 │
# │ ---  ┆ ---  │
# │ str  ┆ str  │
# ╞══════╪══════╡
# │ 2000 ┆ 10K+ │
# │ 10K+ ┆ 10K+ │
# │ 10K+ ┆ 9000 │
# │ 10K+ ┆ 10K+ │
# │ 10K+ ┆ 10K+ │
# └──────┴──────┘

You can't use then('10+') because it interprets it as a column reference. For this, you need to wrap it with pl.lit.
The answer will necessarily have to has type str. You can't place the value 10K+ in an integer column. Alternatively, I suppose if you must retain the integer data type, you could think of all 10K+ values as "may as well be infinity" (math.inf). But, of course, because you cannot do meaningful arithmetic with those values, that hugely reduces the value of keeping them as integers.

Addendum. Because apply, map, and applymap are all pandas.DataFrame methods, if your question is asking for a Pandas explanation instead, just assign pdf[pdf > 10_000] = '10K+'. Results are cast to dtype object.
